# distance between line and point canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I have an upper line and a bottom line. Each line consist of a starting point and and ending point **new line** (**x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end**)

Then I have a rectangle with position x and y. And any value of x, I want to get the vertical distance between there upper line and the bottom.

[image]

My strategy was find the coordonates of intersection of each line (top and bottom) with an imaginary vertical line (x,0, x,10)

I used this code but it does not support infinite slope.

```
function lineIntersect(a, b) {
    a.m = (a[0].y - a[1].y) / (a[0].x - a[1].x);  // slope of line 1
    b.m = (b[0].y - b[1].y) / (b[0].x - b[1].x);  // slope of line 2
    return a.m - b.m < Number.EPSILON ? undefined
        : {
            x: (a.m * a[0].x - b.m * b[0].x + b[0].y - a[0].y) / (a.m - b.m),
            y: (a.m * b.m * (b[0].x - a[0].x) + b.m * a[0].y - a.m * b[0].y) / (b.m - a.m)
        };
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of a line `a=(x0,y0, x1,y1)` with a vertical line through `x=xp` is the same as calculating the `y` coordinate in the line for x==xp.

When the line `a` is vertical (x0=x1) there's no solution (draw it and see why).

```
function getYinLine(a, xp) {
    return Math.abs(a[0].x - a[1].x) < Number.EPSILON ? undefined
        :  a[0].y + (a[1].y - a[0].y) / (a[1].x - a[0].x) * (xp - a[0].x);
}
```

Because the line `a` is really a segment, you should also check bounds `x0 <= xp <= x1`

The vertical distance between the two lines is the difference in y-coordinate:

```
y1 = getYinLine(a, xp);
y2 = getYinLine(b, xp);
if(typeof y1 !== "undefined" && typeof y2 !== "undefined")
    dist = Math.abs(y1-y2);
else
  //do error handling
```